# How can I position a div underneath a paragraph in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a page layout like this:

```
<p>some text</p>
<div>a block button</div>
```

Style on the `<p>`:

```
p {
    font-size: 0.9em;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #666;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
    line-height: 0.6em;
}
```

Style on the `<div>`:

```
.view {
    width: 75px;
    height: 20px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0 3px 3px 0;
    line-height: 1.4em;
}
```

I can't change this (it's generated and shared elsewhere), I can only change the style.

At the moment the `<div>` is rendered to the right of the `<p>`. I need the `<div>` to sit underneath it instead. How can I achieve this in CSS alone (no jQuery)?

Thanks

Comment: By default, it should work as you describe.  There are other styles causing the paragraph to float.

Comment: What are the current styles being applied to the `p` and the `div`. It sounds like one of them is `floated` or the div is `inline-block`. Without knowing this we can guess at a solution, but can't give you an exact answer.

Answer (score 1):

try the following

```
<p>some text</p>
<div style="clear:both">a block button</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
p,
div
{
    display:block;
}
```

This is what the elements are by default something might be overriding your CSS

Answer (score 0):

```
p
{
clear:both;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}
```